# Android is ignoring /res/values-large/strings.xml

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to use a different string resource on small screens but Android always uses the default string. Am I doing it wrong?

/res/values/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="continue">Continue</string>
</resources>
```

/res/values-large/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="continue">Continue to Next Page</string>
</resources>
```

`@string/continue` always resolves to "Continue", even on large screens. It does, however use the dimensions in `/res/values-large/dimens.xml` so I'm sure I'm using the right resource qualifier. I also tried `/res/values-w550dp/strings.xml` and it didn't work either.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values-large` is only available for `dimens` and `styles`, but not for `string` resources.

one could possibly add custom `string-array`s and then look them up accordingly.

see Android [Resource Types](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources).